# how to display or set a non selectable text on choice box in java?

Tags: java, awt

I have taken 3 chice boxes to enter date of birth and i have added the data items in choice boxes but I want to display some text on the choice boxes like "Date","Month" and "year" . And it will also will like the items of combo box but it can not be selected.
program code is :-

```
Choice  dd, mm, yy;

    dd = new Choice();
    mm = new Choice();
    yy = new Choice();

    for(int i = 1; i<=31; i++)
    {
        if(i>=1 && i <= 9)
        dd.addItem("0" + i);
        else if(i>=10 && i<=31)
        dd.addItem("" + i);
    }
    for(int i = 1; i<=12; i++)
    {
        if(i>=1 && i <= 9)
        mm.addItem("0" + i);
        else if(i>=10 && i<=12)
        mm.addItem("" + i);
    }   
    for(int i = 1960; i<=2014; i++)
        yy.addItem("" + i);

    add(dd);
    add(mm);
    add(yy);
```

please give the simplest way to do this. 
please help me.

Comment: AWT is quite dated, better use swing or if you have java 8 JavaFX. AWT relies on the the platform components, and cannot as easily be customized. Swing is a more full model.

Comment: I agree, SWING is much easier to use because you can choose how the interface will look, make the setting for it's component through an API and the code will be generated.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `dd.addItem("Day")` etc. and don't mind it to be selectable. You have to validate the selection anyways (31.02.2014) and return a "problem" message. So you can add the check for "day", etc. to your validation.